# Learning CSS : Why does this code work?

Tags: html, css

I am taking a CSS course on codeschool.com and I am confused by a specific code. I was supposed to edit the code to test a specific function of CSS and I got the answer right, but I don't understand why the code actually works. Here is the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Sven's Snowshoe Emporium</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="home" class="content home group">
      <aside>
        <p>Did you know that Sven's Snowshoe Emporium produces the highest quality snowshoes                        in North America? <a href="#">Find out more</a>.</p>
      </aside>
      <article>
        <h3>New Fall Styles</h3>
        <p>Be the first at your resort to sport the hot new tennis-themed snow kicks, now available in the <a href="#">store</a>.</p>
        <a class="button" href="#">See all products</a>
      </article>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS is

```
.home a {
  color: #c09e79;
}
article .button {
  color: #fff;
}
```

I am confused because in the html code, 'button' is a class, so I thought it would be identified in CSS as #button, not .button

Comment: No, it's definitely denoted by `.button`. Did codeschool.com say otherwise?

Comment: Class noted as `.` while Id as `#`, also pay attention to the fact you set `id="home"` but on the CSS you use `.` which represent a class.

Comment: If codeschool.com does not tell even this, why would anyone use it to learn CSS? Besides, any decent CSS tutorial tells you to always accompany `color` setting with `background` setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.home` selects a class

`#home` selects an id

Id's are used once in a document and classes can be used several times. Elements can also have several classes but only one id.

In your code you have an element with both the id `home` and the class `home`. So either `.home` or `#home` would work.

Answer (score 5):

A fullstop in front of a word denotes it ass a class, a hash tag means it is an id.

Typically Id's are used only once in a document and Class repeatedly

```
#james{
 color:#FFF;
}
.Tom{
 color:#000;
}
.Big{
 font-size:4em;
}
```

The first one can only be accesed with 'id="James"' whereas the second with 'class="Tom"

You can have multiple classes on an object but only one id, to add an extra class you just put a space in.

```
class="Tom Big"
```

Answer (score 3):

In CSS classes are identified by a `.` before the classname. ID's are identified bij a `#`. Tags are identified by only its name.

- `<a class="class_example">` is identified in CSS by `.class_example { ... }`
- `<a id="id_example">` is identified in CSS by `#id_example { ... }`
- `<a>` is identified in CSS by `a { ... }`

You can also stack the selectors on top of each other for specific selections:

- `<a class="class_example" id="id_example">` can be identified by `a.class_example#id_example { ... }`

Keep in mind that in this case all of the first three identifiers will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the difference between Tag Name, Id, and Class

```
div
#id
.class
```

http://jsfiddle.net/weissman258/Hw6gu/

Answer (score 0):

```
/* all anchors (a tags) inside all elements that have class='home' will get this  */
.home a {
  color: #c09e79;
}

/* all elements with class='button' that are inside tag with name article will recieve this */
article .button {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code might work for you in some browsers because they're designed to function even when code is wrong. If a class and id are mismatched, the property might only apply to the classed item the first time. However, if an item has class "home" and it's styled with #home, it's almost certainly going to break in most cases.